# Animate CATextLayer character by character

Tags: ios, core-animation

How can I animate the string of a CATextLayer character by character using CAAnimation? (ex: fade in a character, then fade in the next character and so on...).

Edit: I want to use the text layer with animation for a video overlay.

Comment: Use this library: https://github.com/overboming/ZCAnimatedLabel

Comment: I want to use the layer for a video overlay so the label won't work.

Comment: Hey there! Did you solved it?